# curl - suppress certificate verification error text, not error itself

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, certificate

Whenever I use curl and get error 60 (SSL certificate problem) it also shows me big wall of text:

> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
>
> If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in the URL).
>
> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option.

How can i hide *only* this wall of text?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to supress the warning, use the flag:

**-s, --silent**

If you want to connect to the server despite the certificate issues, use the following flag:

**-k (or --insecure)**

Comment: I don't want to suppress error itself, only quoted wall of text. With `-k` option connection will be established, which is undesirable result.

Comment: Even with -s I get provided in question wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

Use both **-k** and **-s** results in wall of text output. You need to suppress stdout as:

`curl -sk <url>  1>/dev/null`